# My SQL workbench wont allow me to edit anything

Tags: mysql, database, user-interface, mysql-workbench

I have downloaded the mySQL workbench and connected my DB but I need to edit a user in the Users and Privileges tab but it wont allow me to edit any of the `Account Limits` , `Admin. Roles` , `Schema Priviledges`, it also wont let me `Delete`. All of these actions are grayed out and disabled. My computer wont allow me to download mySQL server I am running my bd through Docker so I cant edit the user through the command line. SO I am wondering if this is a common problem? Or something I need to change in the settings? Out of the box the workbench hasnt allowed me to perform these actions. Any advice on what I could be missing would be so helpful

Comment: This is likely due to the user and it's permissions you are using to log into the database (I would assume). Also, what is preventing you from dropping into the command line of the docker container to interact with the database from that command line?

Comment: Oo I didnt realize I could use docker command line. I am very new to backend work Ill try that out. Thanks! @JNevill